# Should glob.glob(...) be preferred over os.listdir(...) or the other way around?

Tags: python, list, glob

If I'd like to create a list of all .xls files, I usually use

```
rdir=r"d:\temp"
flist=[os.path.join(rdir,fil) for fil in os.listdir(rdir) if fil.endswith(".xls")]
print flist
```

However, I recently saw an alternative to this, which is

```
rdir=r"d:\temp"
import glob
flist=glob.glob(os.path.join(rdir,"*.xls"))
print flist
```

Which of these two methods is to be preferred and why? Or are they considered equally (un)sound?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are fine. Also consider `os.path.walk` if you actually want to do something with that list (rather then building the list for its own sake).

Comment: for python 3 it's os.walk

Answer (score 6):

I'd personally go with `glob.glob`, as it's clearer.
However, as it's a wrapper around `listdir`, they both get the job done.